(AMBER) Questioning how mask works in MMPBSA
Note: this question was also posted on the AMBER mailing list, but I reposted this question here because I needed answers for this question quickly. Sorry if this is violating any rules...
Dear AMBER Users,
Hello, I am trying to run a alanine scanning of the protein EGFR, which is connected to the ligand Lapatinib.
After making the required .prmtop files, I went through the following command:
$AMBERHOME/bin/MMPBSA.py -O -i mmpbsa.in -sp EGFR_FMM_solvated.prmtop -cp EGFR_FMM.prmtop -rp EGFR.prmtop -lp FMM.prmtop -y *.mdcrd -mc EGFR_FMM_mutant.prmtop -mr EGFR_mutant.prmtop

and I got the following error:
Loading and checking parameter files for compatibility...
 File "/home/hjs/MD/amber24/bin/MMPBSA.py", line 98, in <module>
   app.loadcheck_prmtops()
 File "/home/hjs/MD/amber24/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MMPBSA_mods/main.py", line 652, in loadcheck_prmtops
   self.normal_system.CheckConsistency()
 File "/home/hjs/MD/amber24/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MMPBSA_mods/parm_setup.py", line 931, in CheckConsistency
   raise PrmtopError('Inconsistent charge definition for atom %d!' %
PrmtopError: Inconsistent charge definition for atom 4747!

Fatal Error!
All files have been retained for your error investigation:
You should begin by examining the output files of the first failed calculation.
Consult the "Temporary Files" subsection of the MMPBSA.py chapter in the
manual for file naming conventions.

After this, I checked with parmed:
The original EGFR+FMM(protein-ligand complex) file's mask @4747 looked like this:
ATOM    RES  RESNAME  NAME  TYPE   At.#   LJ Radius    LJ Depth      Mass    Charge GB Radius GB Screen
4747    290      MOL    P1    p5     15      2.1000      0.2000   30.9700    1.2430    1.8500    0.8600
While the mutant one (LYS196 changed to ALA) looked like this:
ATOM    RES  RESNAME  NAME  TYPE   At.#   LJ Radius    LJ Depth      Mass    Charge GB Radius GB Screen
4747    292      MOL    O1     o      8      1.6612      0.2100   16.0000   -0.6513    1.5000    0.8500
So, how does this "mask" system work, and why does the mask @4747 points to different atoms?
The original EGFR+FMM file looks like:
ATOM   3074  HG  SER A 195      28.092  42.091  22.178  1.00 31.68           H
ATOM   3075  N   LYS A 196      30.381  40.198  25.948  1.00 35.98           N
ATOM   3076  CA  LYS A 196      30.998  40.103  27.264  1.00 36.17           C
ATOM   3077  C   LYS A 196      31.857  41.352  27.423  1.00 36.37           C
ATOM   3078  O   LYS A 196      32.656  41.681  26.543  1.00 36.66           O
ATOM   3079  CB  LYS A 196      31.878  38.854  27.355  1.00 37.51           C
ATOM   3080  CG  LYS A 196      31.041  37.603  27.084  1.00 37.84           C
ATOM   3081  CD  LYS A 196      31.930  36.367  27.201  1.00 40.09           C
ATOM   3082  CE  LYS A 196      32.370  36.197  28.656  1.00 41.89           C
ATOM   3083  NZ  LYS A 196      33.435  35.160  28.749  1.00 43.62           N
ATOM   3084  H   LYS A 196      30.914  39.756  25.199  1.00 35.98           H
ATOM   3085  HA  LYS A 196      30.242  40.030  28.046  1.00 36.17           H
ATOM   3086  HB2 LYS A 196      32.693  38.920  26.634  1.00 37.51           H
ATOM   3087  HB3 LYS A 196      32.332  38.790  28.344  1.00 37.51           H
ATOM   3088  HG2 LYS A 196      30.217  37.541  27.795  1.00 37.84           H
ATOM   3089  HG3 LYS A 196      30.600  37.655  26.089  1.00 37.84           H
ATOM   3090  HD2 LYS A 196      31.388  35.482  26.867  1.00 40.09           H
ATOM   3091  HD3 LYS A 196      32.802  36.469  26.555  1.00 40.09           H
ATOM   3092  HE2 LYS A 196      32.740  37.145  29.046  1.00 41.89           H
ATOM   3093  HE3 LYS A 196      31.517  35.910  29.271  1.00 41.89           H
ATOM   3094  HZ1 LYS A 196      34.044  35.360  29.568  1.00 43.62           H
ATOM   3095  HZ2 LYS A 196      32.998  34.223  28.863  1.00 43.62           H
ATOM   3096  HZ3 LYS A 196      34.008  35.172  27.881  1.00 43.62           H
ATOM   3097  N   PRO A 197      31.695  42.077  28.540  1.00 36.61           N

while the mutant file looks like:
ATOM   3074  HG  SER A 195      28.092  42.091  22.178  1.00 31.68           H
ATOM   3075  N   ALA A 196      30.381  40.198  25.948  1.00 35.98           N
ATOM   3076  CA  ALA A 196      30.998  40.103  27.264  1.00 36.17           C
ATOM   3077  C   ALA A 196      31.857  41.352  27.423  1.00 36.37           C
ATOM   3078  O   ALA A 196      32.656  41.681  26.543  1.00 36.66           O
ATOM   3079  CB  ALA A 196      31.878  38.854  27.355  1.00 37.51           C
ATOM   3084  H   ALA A 196      30.914  39.756  25.199  1.00 35.98           H
ATOM   3085  HA  ALA A 196      30.242  40.030  28.046  1.00 36.17           H
ATOM   3097  N   PRO A 197      31.695  42.077  28.540  1.00 36.61           N

Thank you for your time and help.
